# TFS API TeamProjectCollection GetService<IBuildServer>() returns null object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I have written below code to queue a build via api. team project collection, workitem store  and version control server works fine, but i am not getting buildserver object. its always returning null. am i missing any other configuration

```
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")))
{
    tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

    // i am getting workitemstore object here
    var wiStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    ....
    ....

    // i am getting version control server object here as well
    var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    ....
    ....

    // but here i get a null object
    var bs = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();

    //this is what i want to do with buildserver object
    var buildDefinition = bs.GetBuildDefinition("aaa", "bbb");
    var buildRequest = buildDefinition.CreateBuildRequest();
    bs.QueueBuild(buildRequest);
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you reference the wrong version of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client` for the TFS that you're trying to connect to.  Check that you're referencing the correct version for TFS2010 (10.0.0.0 I believe).

http://pmichaels.net/2015/03/20/unable-to-get-ibuildserver-always-returning-null/

Answer (score 0):

Try `var bs = (IBuildServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));` Sometimes the `GetService<>()` didn't work for me, maybe because IBuildServer is an interface, while VersionControlServer for example is a class.

Comment: I haven't used this specific part of code for a while, because it was TFS2010 code, but we switched to TFS2012, inspired by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/03/28/adding-build-steps-to-team-build-in-orcas.aspx 
Your tpc is correctly initiated at that point, right? Usually I would think that every collection has a BuildServer. Is your project configuration "Any CPU"? If not, switch it to it.

Comment: Yes, my project configuration is Release | Any CPU and the build works fine when we trigger it manually.

Comment: I took your code, removed the WorkItemStore and VersionControlServer part, changed the url to our TFS 2012 system, used an existing TeamProject and BuildDefinition name and the bs variable gets set and I'm able to start a build. So the code in general is ok. Are you able to run builds from your collection in TFS?

Comment: Is there any settings or configuration to make buildserver available in the context of project collection?

Comment: You are using VS2010 and TFS2010 right? Is there any other version of Visual Studio installed on the machine you run your code? I have read about similiar issues when other versions were installed and wrong references were used in the project.